# how to solve storage question for apache httpd cluster?

Tags: storage, cluster-computing, apache

I'm planning to set up an Apache HTTPD cluster for failover and loadbalancing. I have a typical LAMP stack and MySQL is already clustered on different servers. As I do not use sessions, I don't have to care about PHP session management, but I have to keep the file synchronized between the (active) HTTPDs. All server are dedicated servers at a webhoster.

What is the best practice to keep the files synchronized?

NFS? What if server1 and server2 write at the same time?
How to handle the heavy I/O accesses without creating a bottleneck?

Best Regards from Berlin/Germany

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [RedHat GFS](http://www.redhat.com/gfs/).  As a note, it's supported on distros other than RedHat.